# Wrapper stopped successful message and wrapper service stopping status is not in sync

Tags: java, yajsw

I'm using YAJSW version stable 12.15 to wrap a Java web application. I have both start and stop configuration files.  Everything works fine but what I see when I launched stopmyservice.bat file to stop the service it shows **"Service xyz stopped"** however at that time when I looked at the windows service section it says still stopping and it eventually stopped after the java program terminated.

Can someone please help me, how this stopped successfully message can be in sync with the wrapper service, right now it comes before the service fully stopped?

I want the bat to wait until the service completely stopped.

Thanks